# How to align several div tags without vertical align?

Tags: html, css

I got homework from my web dev courses to make a webpage looking like this: [pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHfn7.jpg)

We are not allowed to use display flex or vertical align tags as we still haven't learnt them, no images as well.

My problem is three div elements at the bottom, no matter what I try they wont align with each other(Image 2 div, header div and info box div):[looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9zRh.png)

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
  padding:0;
  font-family: 'Balsamiq Sans', cursive;
}

.logo{
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: black;
  color:white;
  width:115px;
  height:85px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-left: 30px;
}
.text{
  text-align: center;
}

.banner{
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  width: 90%;
  height: 85px;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.btext{
  text-align: center;
}

.nav{
  background-color: black;
  color:white;
  margin:45px 11px 0 11px;
  padding: 3px 0 3px 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav li{
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  padding-right: 120px;
}

.img{
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: crimson;
  color: white;
  width:450px;
  height: 550px;
  margin:15px 0 0 25px;
}

.imgtext{
  text-align: center;
  padding-top:200px;
}

.htext{
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 150px;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.info{
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: skyblue;
  color: white;
  width: 450px;
  height: 550px;
  margin: 15px 0 0 350px
}
.infotext{
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 22px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Balsamiq+Sans:ital,wght@1,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

  <div class='logo'>
    <div class='text'>
      <h1>LOGO</h1>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class='banner'>
    <div class='btext'>
      <h1>BANNER</h1>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class='nav'>
    <ul>
      <li>HOME</li>
      <li>PROJECTS</li>
      <li>STORE</li>
      <li>CONTACT</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="img">
    <div class='imgtext'>
      <h1>IMAGE 2</h1>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="htext">
    <h1>Header 1</h1>
    <span>Random letters and numbers etcetcetc</span>
  </div>

  <div class="info">
    <div class='infotext'>
      <h1>What?</h1>
      <span>This is information about the website</span>
      <h1>Where?</h1>
      <span>This website was created in St.Louis,MO.</span>
      <h1>How?</h1>
      <span>Visit our contact page for more information.</spam>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: *We are not allowed to use display flex or vertical align tags as we still haven't learnt them* --> sorry but I don't think it's a good way to learn.

Comment: ^ to fix your issue you **have** to use vertical-align:top on inline-block elements. This is how CSS works. Learning inline-block imply also learning vertical-align